# JQuery Append if condition for select box

Tags: jquery

**Could someone please help on how to add if condition to the below snippet?**

Snippet:

```
function editStudesnt(data) {
$('#studentInfo').empty();
$('#studentInfo').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
"<span id=\"lb\">Student Name:"+data.stuName+"</span></div>"+
"<label>Student Id: </label>"+
"<span id=\"SID\">"+data.stuId +"</span><br />");
 }
```

**How do I add an if condition to the above snippet in the case where I need a condition as**

For example,

```
if(data.courseId==1){
<label>Student Course: </label> <select id=\"courseId\"><option value="" selected="selected">Mechanical</option><option value=\"1\" selected="\selected\">Mechanical</option><option value=\"2\">Computer Science</option><option value=\"2\">Electronics</option></select>"
}
if(data.courseId==2){
<label>Student Course: </label> <select id=\"courseId\"><option value="" selected="selected">Mechanical</option><option value=\"1\" >Mechanical</option><option value=\"2\" selected="\selected\">Computer Science</option><option value=\"2\">Electronics</option></select>"
}
```

The above code is working fine. But the problem is when I have more courses, the same codes repeats in every conditions. So can anyone please provide me a solution where I can write the if condition inside the option say, MechanicalComputer Science.

Comment: Are you wanting to append that to the `#studentInfo` element?

Comment: Could you please explain in words rather than just pasting the code and expecting us to understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
just add below in function 

function editStudesnt(data) {
$('#studentInfo').empty();
$('#studentInfo').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
"<span id=\"lb\">Student Name:"+data.stuName+"</span></div>"+
"<label>Student Id: </label>"+
"<span id=\"SID\">"+data.stuId +"</span><br />");

if(data.courseId==1){
 $('#studentInfo').append("<label>Student Course: </label> <select id=\"courseId\"><option value="" selected="selected">Mechanical</option><option value=\"1\" selected="\selected\">Mechanical</option><option value=\"2\">Computer Science</option><option value=\"2\">Electronics</option></select>");
}
if(data.courseId==2){
$('#studentInfo').append("<label>Student Course: </label> <select id=\"courseId\"><option value="" selected="selected">Mechanical</option><option value=\"1\" >Mechanical</option><option value=\"2\" selected="\selected\">Computer Science</option><option value=\"2\">Electronics</option></select>")
}

 }
```

want to do like this?

Comment: The things you have written is correct. But the problem is when i have more courses, the same codes repeats in every conditions. So can anyone please provide me a solution where I can write the if condition inside the option say, <option value=if(data.courseId==1) selected="selected">Mechanical</option><option value=if(data.courseId==2) selected="selected">Computer Science</option>

Answer (score 0):

it would be much cleaner to build up the controls as controls, so

```
var select = $("<select></select");
var option = $("<option></option>");
option.text("hello")
option.val("2");
if(data.val == option.val()) option.attr("selected", "selected");
select.append(option);
```